# Как исправить оператор ввода в поток (<<) строкового представления объекта?

Tags: c++

Имею некоторую структуру `Sample`, в которой реализованы базовые операции над ней. Мне потребовался оператор `<<` для ввода ее строкового представления в `std::cout`. Проблема в том, что я не могу вывести результат, к примеру, сложения двух объектов `Sample`, не записав его в другой объект. Я не хочу этого делать так как желаю упростить запись.

### Иллюстрационный пример

```
#include <iostream>

struct Sample
{
    int value;

    Sample(int Value) :
        value(Value)
    {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Sample& it)
    {
        os << "Sample(" << it.value << ')';
        return os;
    }

    friend Sample operator+(const Sample& S1, const Sample& S2)
    {
        return Sample(S1.value + S2.value);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Sample A(3);
    Sample B(4);

    // Можно так:
    std::cout << A << std::endl;
    std::cout << B << std::endl;
    // Но не так:
    //std::cout << A + B << std::endl;
    //std::cout << (A + B) << std::endl;
    //std::cout << ... << std::endl;
    // Желаю упростить запись:
    Sample C = A + B;
    std::cout << C << std::endl;
    // Проблема: ?

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод (*не важен*):

```
Sample(3)
Sample(4)
Sample(7)
```

Visual Studio о `.. << A + B << ..` говорит: `C++ отсутствует оператор, соответствующий этим операндам типы операндов: std::ostream << Sample`, а о `.. << A << ..` говорит `C++ std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Sample &it)`. Наталкивает на то, что я должен как-то изменить параметры `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Sample& it)`, но что конкретно мне нужно сделать - я не могу понять. Убрать `std::ostream& os`? И в что тогда записывать?

### Сам вопрос

Как мне исправить `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Sample& it)`, чтобы я мог записывать как `std::cout << A << std::endl;` , так и `std::cout << A + B << std::endl;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Sample& it)
```